# Micro-batching through Nifi

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I have a scenario where my kafka messages(from same topic) are flowing through single enrichment pipeline and written at the end into HDFS and MongoDB. My Kafka consumer for HDFS will run on hourly basis(for micro-batching). So I need to know the best possible way to route flowfiles to putHDFS and putMongo based on which consumer it is coming from(Consumer for HDFS or consumer for Mongo DB).

Or please suggest if there is any other way to achieve micro-batching through Nifi.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could set Nifi up to use a [Scheduling Strategy](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#scheduling-strategy) for the processors that upload data.

And I would think you want the Kafka consumers to always read data, building a backlog of FlowFiles in NiFi, and then having the puts run on a less-frequent basis.

---

This is similar to how Kafka Connect would run for its HDFS Connector

Comment: Yes so I have two kafka Consumer processor in Nifi, one to serve speed layer which saves data in MongoDB and other for batch layer which saves in HDFS. So the second processor is scheduled on hourly basis. But messages from both the processors go through single enrichment pipeline before written into respective databases. So my question revolves around how am I going to differentiate between messages and route them to correct databases.

Comment: It's been a while since I used NiFi. I don't think you can have a single pipeline. Not without copying the FlowFiles somehow before they are sent to a downsteam. That being said, might be better to use two separate Kafka consumer processors, with different group ids